# Replace second tuple value in list of tuples

Tags: list, haskell, replace, tuples

I have a list A, `[('a', 3), ('b', 0), ('c',0)]`, and want to replace `('b',0)` with `('b', 13)`. 
And return a new list B, `[('a', 3), ('b', 13), ('c',0)]`. How do I do this in haskell?

Thanks

Comment: This question shows no research effort. Please read about [How To Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to replace all occurences of `('b', 0)` then you can use `map`:

```
b = map (\p -> if p == ('b', 0) then ('b', 13) else p) a
```

If you want to replace the second value if the first element is 'b' then you can do:

```
map (\p@(f, _) -> if f == 'b' then ('b', 13) else p) l
```

Comment: great, I knew map would be able to do it but I didn't know the syntax... Can I modify it so that the tuple is replaced only if I know the first value, 'b'?

Comment: @Lee Check out this answer about [answering homework questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10812/181417).

Answer (score 0):

You may also do as follows;

```
set :: (Char,Int) -> [(Char,Int)] -> [(Char,Int)]
set (k,v) []                  = []
set (k,v) (t:ts) | k == fst t = (k,v) : ts
                 | otherwise  = t : set (k,v) ts
```